# Integer value returns 0 after trying to convert it from string

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

I have variable like this with the type of `string`:

```
$price = "65000"
```

Now I tried setting it's type to `integer`, so I tried these:

```
$finalprice = (int)$price; // returns 0
$finalprice = (intval)$price; // returns 0
```

So how to properly return the value `65000` as integer?

Comment: How does `$finalprice = (int)$price;` return 0? How do you check it, because that works normally. Also, that's not the correct use of `intval`, `intval` is a function which requires a variable as parameter.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a currency symbol in the price? If `$price = "65000";` then setting it to an integer will be `65000` - however, `(int) "£65000"` would be `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrong code, the first it's correct and the second is `intval($variable)`

```
$price = "65000";

$finalprice1 = (int) $price; 
$finalprice2 = intval($price);
var_dump($finalprice1);
var_dump($finalprice2);

/*
int(65000)
int(65000)
*/
```

I hope it's just a typing error but in the variable you didn't close with `;`

---

Another method you can use is `settype` like:

```
$price = "65000";
settype($price,'int');
var_dump($price);

/*
int(65000)
*/
```

Reference:

- [intval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)
- [settype](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php)